# how use mongoexport to export only specific fields in a sub-document

Tags: json, mongodb

is there a way to export only specified fields in a sub-document while using mongoexport? mongo docs says to just use -f field1, field2 etc... but that only works with top level fields. i have a document inside of the main document that also has fields. is there any way to get only those?

Example:

```
{
    "topField1": "topValue1",
    "topField2": "topValue2",
    "subDoc1: {
                  "subField1": "subValue1",
                  "subField2": "subValue2"
              }
}
```

is there a way to specify that i ONLY get the field subField2?

i know in a regular mongo query i could use "subDoc1.subField2" which would simply 
`return {"$oid": 122432432, {"subDoc1":{"subField2": "subValue2"}}` but this doesn't seem to work with `mongoexport`.

also i want to export as `json`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

what kind of error do you get using dotnotation? I'm running mongoDB 1.8.2 and for me the following works:

```
mongoexport -d dbName -c collectionName -f subDoc1.subField2 --csv -o /path/to/file.csv
```

The CSV looks like this

```
subDoc1.subField2 #header with field names
"subValue2" #actual entry
```

Comment: i don't think i was getting an error. i think the problem was it was returning unnecessary fields. but you're right it does work now! i think i was previously running mongo 1.6. now i'm running mongo 2.0.1. thanks Demi!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
mongoexport --db db_name --collection collection_name --fields 'No,Name' --out collection_name.json
```

> {"_id":{"$oid":"5b2a1d540e63356357cbff46"},"name":"vijil","dep":"MCA"}
> {"_id":{"$oid":"5b2a1d5e0e63356357cbff47"},"name":"arul","dep":"MCA"}
> {"_id":{"$oid":"5b2a1d670e63356357cbff48"},"name":"abessh","dep":"MCA"}

Comment: this doesn't seem to work, still all fields are being exported

Comment: same than yours. I tried to avoid exporting the _id field, but it seems to not be possible using json. works only if exported to csv flag. see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12976145/mongoexport-without-id-field)

Answer (score -1):

In case we are not sure of the subdocument value .i.e in this case : `subField1` or `subField2`, but what we need is just to extract the first field of the sub-collection.
Can mongoexport handle that ?